# How to get JSON data in Correct format using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm developing an IOS app, and for the API I'm sending my requests to a URL that should return JSON data with PHP
I am Getting like

```
[{"Child Care":"After Scool,Breakfast Club\n"},{"Child Care":"Breakfast Club"}]
```

But I want to get like

```
[{

"Childcare":[

"All of Childcare",

"After school",

"Breakfast Club"
]}
```

My code is

```
    <?php
session_start();
$connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','testing') or die(mysqli_error());

    $sql="select `Child Care` from Activity_type ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $emparray=array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push($emparray,$row);
        }   
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($emparray); 

    ?>
```

Comment: post here what you got

Comment: [{"Child Care":"After Scool,Breakfast Club\n"},{"Child Care":"Breakfast Club"}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put it in your `JSON` array properly.

```
$emparray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $emparray['Child Care'][] = $row['Child Care'];
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

---

To answer your second question from the comments:

```
$emparray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        $emparray[$key][] = $val;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

Comment: Pleasure mate @SaiKumar

Comment: If I have 7 Coloumns like 'Childcare' what can i do @Darren

Comment: How exactly do you want the data to be passed through?

Comment: I have 7 Columns in a table i want get like [{

"Childcare":[

"All of Childcare",

"After school",] "Classes":[

"All of Classes",

"Antenatal",].........}

Comment: Ya Got it tnq @darren

Comment: How to remove empty array values in json code @Darren

Answer (score 1):

This will give the format you want.Let me know if this works for you.

```
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($emparray,$row['Child Care']);
}   
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("Childcare" => $emparray));
```

Comment: No its getting error like <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 0 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\activitytype.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
{"Childcare":[null,null]}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like,

```
$sql="select `Child Care` from Activity_type ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
$emparray=array();

while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $cares = explode(',' $row['Child Care']);
    foreach($cares as $care){
      $emparray[] = $care;
  }
}   

header('Content-Type: application/json');    
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

Use php `explode` function